Microsoft Edge <select> gap mouseout issue
In Microsoft Edge, there is a gap between the <select> menu and its options when you expand the menu, like this:

This can lead to issues with the mouseout event since the behavior is not consistent with Chrome. Consider this minimal example:


const menu = document.getElementById('menu');

menu.addEventListener('mouseout', (e) => {
  // The line below fixes the glitch in Firefox, but not Edge
  if (e.relatedTarget === null) return;
  document.body.classList.toggle('red');
});
.red {
  background: red;
}
<select id="menu">
  <option>One</option>
  <option>Two</option>
  <option>Three</option>
</select>



In Edge and only in Edge, when you move the mouse cursor between the menu and its expanded options, it triggers the mouseout event. How do you prevent this behavior in Edge?

Can repro. This might just be something worth reporting.

Sounds like (until this bug is fixed) you need to look up the x and y properties of the event and check it against the x/y coordinates of the select element

@Carcigenicate Microsoft doesn't seem to have a bug tracker for Edge. I submitted a report using "Send feedback" in the menu, but who knows if it will be looked at.

Can't test this right now, but what happens when you wrap the select in an additional span - and then listen for mouseout event on the span instead?

@CBroe that didn't work.

I tried CBroe's suggestion of wrapping the select in a span. My span looks like:
<span id="wrapper" style="height:20px; display:inline-block">

Then I listen for mouseleave event on the wrapper (mouseout won't work in this case). This works just fine. Looks like the space between select and listbox is just shorter than 20px, and is of fixed height. You can have a try.

Can you please share a jsfiddle? It's still not working for me: https://jsfiddle.net/thdoan/kev4Lsha/1/

@thdoan In jsfiddle you need to give it a height of 25px. Normally if you use an independent HTML file, 20px is just fine. At least for me it works.

Thanks, I got it to work using a bigger height.
